# How are hair and beard lengths maintained in space?

Tags: iss, microgravity, hygiene

From the question [What are the regulations governing (against) beards in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12607) we know that hair and beard length are not regulated on the ISS.  For the most part pictures indicate both men and women keep their hair maintained.

I know when using electrical trimmers at home there are small pieces of hair, that gravity bring to the ground, and they get washed or vacuumed away.  In the ISS they would just float around until someone inhaled them, or they got caught someplace.

How is hair maintenance managed on the ISS?  Is trimming limited to only the head (i.e. is body hair below the neck line trimmed in space)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[A haircut](http://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/eng/astronauts/living-in-space/personal-hygiene-in-space.asp) is done with an electric trimmer which has a vacuum hose attached.

Wet shaving avoids this by trapping the cuttings in shaving foam, but some astronauts use electric razors, again with a vacuum hose.

Here's a video of someone using an electric trimmer: [Shaving in space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or2tzAkkbkM)

Comment: And if you want to get a haircut like the astronauts, it looks like Flowbee is still available online, even if they're not running commercials anymore : https://www.flowbee.com/

Comment: Is Flowbee like the Suck-Cut? It cuts as it sucks...

Comment: @Rory Alsop: It certainly does suck ;p

Comment: It's how you get your hair cut in military barbers - an electric trimmer connected to a clear plastic hose going to a shop-vac. Classy...